# obtaining a list of objects from a complex nested object in terraform

Tags: for-loop, nested, terraform

I am trying to create a local variable **"secret_list"** in terraform based on a variable **"secrets"** that is defined in a tfvars.json file.

The **"secrets"** variable looks like this:

```json
{
"secrets" : {
        "datacore": {
            "secrets" : [
                {"secret_scope": "datacore", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-databricks-deploy", "secret_value": "dummy"},
                {"secret_scope": "datacore", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-datacore", "secret_value": "dummy"}
            ],
            "acls" : [
                {"secret_scope": "datacore", "principal": "admins", "permission": "MANAGE"},
                {"secret_scope": "datacore", "principal": "Datacore Power Users", "permission": "READ"}
            ]
        },
        "ai" : {
            "secrets" : [
                {"secret_scope": "ai", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-ai", "secret_value": "dummy"},
                {"secret_scope": "ai", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-ai-private-key", "secret_value": "dummy"}
            ],
            "acls" : [
                {"secret_scope": "ai", "principal": "admins", "permission": "MANAGE"},
                {"secret_scope": "ai", "principal": "AI Power Users", "permission": "READ"}
            ]
        }
   }
}
```

its structure is described as:

```
variable "secrets" {
    type = map(object({
            secrets = list(
                object({
                    secret_scope = string,
                    secret_key = string,
                    secret_value =string
                })),
            acls = list(
                object({
                    secret_scope = string,
                    principal = string,
                    permission = string
            }))}))
}
```

I want to create a new local variable **"secret_list"** which outputs this:

```
secret_list =  [
{"secret_scope": "datacore", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-databricks-deploy", "secret_value": "dummy"},
{"secret_scope": "datacore", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-databricks-deploy", "secret_value": "dummy"},
{"secret_scope": "ai", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-ai", "secret_value": "dummy"},
{"secret_scope": "ai", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-ai-private-key", "secret_value": "dummy"}
]
```

This is a list of objects that contains all the secrets that are inside the **"secrets"** variable.

I have tried to create a local variable **"secret_list"** using a for loop like this:

```
locals {
    secret_list = {
        value = flatten([
            for secrets in var.secrets : [
                for secret_attributes in secrets.secrets : secret_attributes
            ]
        ])
    }
}
```

and created a new output object to view the result in the console:

```
output "secret_list" {
  value = local.secret_list
}
```

I cannot seem to get the desired output. In the console it looks like:

```json
 secret_list              = {
      + value = [
          + {
              + secret_key   = "serviceaccount-databricks-deploy"
              + secret_scope = "datacore"
              + secret_value = "dummy"
            },
          + {
              + secret_key   = "serviceaccount-datacore"
              + secret_scope = "datacore"
              + secret_value = "dummy"
            },
          + {
              + secret_key   = "serviceaccount-ai"
              + secret_scope = "ai"
              + secret_value = "dummy"
            },
          + {
              + secret_key   = "serviceaccount-ai-private-key"
              + secret_scope = "ai"
              + secret_value = "dummy"
            }
       ]
}
```

How can I get to:

```
secret_list =  [
{"secret_scope": "datacore", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-databricks-deploy", "secret_value": "dummy"},
{"secret_scope": "datacore", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-databricks-deploy", "secret_value": "dummy"},
{"secret_scope": "ai", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-ai", "secret_value": "dummy"},
{"secret_scope": "ai", "secret_key": "serviceaccount-ai-private-key", "secret_value": "dummy"}
]
```

Comment: The only difference between observed and expected is the `value` key, so why not just remove it if you do not want it? Also I assume there is a `jsondecode` hidden somewhere.

Comment: Is there a way to remove that key using terraform expressions? I haven't found a way how. I am not using an explicit jsondecode anywhere. All operations are done using the syntax provided in the post. Also, the expected behavior is a list of objects. the observed behavior is a an object containing a list of objects. Simply removing the key wouldn't be enough. I was hoping to get the expected behavior by using terraform expressions within the for loop when creating the local variable secret_list.

Comment: Actually the observed is a `map(list(object))`, and the only reason the map exists with the value key is because you are adding it in the `for` expression lambda. You do not need to remove it; you need to not add it.

Comment: Hehe, that made me laugh. You are absolutely right. Can you show me how to not add it? I have tried so many things but I don't seem to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the delta between the observed and desired structures, your `locals` block with the `for` expressions:

```
locals {
  secret_list = {
    value = flatten([
      for secrets in var.secrets : [
        for secret_attributes in secrets.secrets : secret_attributes
      ]
    ])
  }
}
```

needs to not specify an outer `map` constructor with a key of `value`. The value of that `map` should be the entire structure:

```
locals {
  secret_list = flatten([
    for secrets in var.secrets : [
      for secret_attributes in secrets.secrets : secret_attributes
    ]
  ])
}
```

Comment: brain fart. This worked off course. Thanks!